# Use of curly braces in signature of pure function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out how the code below works in terms of the `{ active, children, onClick }`. What are the curly braces doing here? I would have expected instead `const Link = (props) =>`, where the values are accessed in the function using props.active etc. This is what I am doing in my CommentBox example below.

Link:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {
  if (active) {
    return <span>{children}</span>
  }

  return (
    <a href="#"
       onClick={e => {
         e.preventDefault()
         onClick()
       }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}
```

FilterLink:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions'
import Link from '../components/Link'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}

const FilterLink = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link)

export default FilterLink
```

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

CommentBox:

```
const CommentBox = ( props ) => 
      <div className="commentBox">
      <h1>Comments</h1>
      { props.comments.valueSeq().map( (comment) =>
                <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
                {comment.text}
                </Comment>
                )}

        <CommentForm />
      </div>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {comments: state.get('comments')};
}
```

Comment: `Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {...` doing the same as `Link=(props)=>{ var active = props.active, children = props.children, onClick = props.onClick; ...}` - its called **destructuring**.

Answer (score 3):

```
const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => { ... });
```

What this is doing is destructuring the first argument. Assuming your first argument is an object with at least `active`, `children` and `onClick` properties, it directly maps them into variables of the same name.

You can see it in action [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=function%20foo(%7Bbar%2C%20baz%7D%2C%20bam)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(bar%2C%20baz%2C%20bam)%0A%7D).

```
// ES6
function foo({bar, baz}, bam){
  console.log(bar, baz)
}

// ES5
"use strict";

function foo(_ref, bam) {
  var bar = _ref.bar;
  var baz = _ref.baz;

  console.log(bar, baz, bam);
}
```

Comment: I think this page gives some good simple examples: http://www.jstips.co/en/use-destructuring-in-function-parameters/